# Does the bgiframe plugin work with jQuery 1.3.x?

Tags: jquery, bgiframe

With jQuery 1.2.6 I would do the below and all was well

```
$("#element").bgiframe();
```

But the only examples I have seen working with jQuery 1.3.x (shown below)

```
$("#element").bgiframe = true;
```

But the above does not work ... so does anyone have a new plugin to do this type of thing?

EDIT:  I'm using this plugin outside of jQuery.UI, and the version I'm using is 2.1.1

Comment: Which version of bgiframe are you using?  Are you using it through jQuery UI?

Comment: 2.1.1 - i didn't realize this was dump'd into jQuery UI ... i actually just included a js file w/ this only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized if I just tweak the js code in the old plugin, it would work with jQuery 1.3.x

The below is the final version of this plugin - working 100% w/ jQuery 1.3.1

Because of a conflict w/ the name I had to rename it to bbgiframe (instead of bgiframe)

So when you call it do so as follows:

```
$("#element").bbgiframe();
```

Now the revised plugin code:

```
$.fn.bbgiframe = function(s) {
    // This is only for IE6
    if ( $.browser.msie && /6.0/.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        s = $.extend({
            top     : 'auto', // auto == .currentStyle.borderTopWidth
            left    : 'auto', // auto == .currentStyle.borderLeftWidth
            width   : 'auto', // auto == offsetWidth
            height  : 'auto', // auto == offsetHeight
            opacity : true,
            src     : 'javascript:false;'
        }, s || {});
        var prop = function(n){return n&&n.constructor==Number?n+'px':n;},
            html = '<iframe class="bbgiframe"frameborder="0"tabindex="-1"src="'+s.src+'"'+
                       'style="display:block;position:absolute;z-index:-1;'+
                           (s.opacity !== false?'filter:Alpha(Opacity=\'0\');':'')+
                           'top:'+(s.top=='auto'?'expression(((parseInt(this.parentNode.currentStyle.borderTopWidth)||0)*-1)+\'px\')':prop(s.top))+';'+
                           'left:'+(s.left=='auto'?'expression(((parseInt(this.parentNode.currentStyle.borderLeftWidth)||0)*-1)+\'px\')':prop(s.left))+';'+
                           'width:'+(s.width=='auto'?'expression(this.parentNode.offsetWidth+\'px\')':prop(s.width))+';'+
                           'height:'+(s.height=='auto'?'expression(this.parentNode.offsetHeight+\'px\')':prop(s.height))+';'+
                    '"/>';
        return this.each(function() {
            if ( $('> iframe.bbgiframe', this).length == 0 )
                this.insertBefore( document.createElement(html), this.firstChild );
        });
    }
    return this;
};
```

Comment: What did you change? This appears to be identical to version 2.1.1 at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe ... no?

Comment: I didn't alter the actual plugin, just how it was defined so jQuery 1.3.x would work.  I'm no plugin developer so I can't tell you what was wrong with the previous, but I can say the above does work with jQuery 1.3.x